# WordPress how to get all custom and default post type slug in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, slug

I have created a custom plugin in WordPress.

Here my requirement is to get **ALL post type slug** including custom / built-in.

For eg : If I have the WooCommerce plugin installed , then the function should return **"product"** post type slug, if I have the LearnDash LMS plugin installed , then function should return **"course"** and many other post type slug , and if I have any custom post type (eg : books ), then function should return "book" post type slug.

for that I am using this code for custom post type :

```
$args = array(
    'public'   => true,
    '_builtin' => false
); 

$output = 'names';
$operator = 'and';

$post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator );
echo "<pre>"; print_r( $post_types );
```

I have WooCommerce plugin installed and also created a custom post type called "book"
but it shows a blank array.

and if I use below code , it is showing buit-in post type , which is correct

```
$post_types = get_post_types();
echo "<pre>"; print_r( $post_types );
```

Comment: The first snippet you provided, works on my end for both `product`, created by woo, and `book`, `hotel` etc., created as custom post types. It leaves out the `builtin` ones and gives you the custom ones! If you get a blank response, then you'd need to look for the bug elsewhere!

Comment: Have you used the first snippet inside any hook ?

Comment: Yes I have! In fact, I had tested it before I posted my comment, and it worked fine!

Comment: I have NOT used the first snippet inside any HOOK , actually, I want an array of post types and then I have to pass that array in another function.

Comment: In the first snippet, `$post_types` variable returns an array. [Please read the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_types/#return).